# Custom syntax highlighting misbehaving in gedit

Tags: xml, gedit, syntax-highlighting

For gedit, I'm creating a custom syntax highlighter for a markup-like language that I created to accomplish some natural language manipulation stuff, so I thought I'd get started with the simple keywords, seeing as I don't need to come up with regexes for them.

I've defined the following in the XML:

```xml
<language id="foo" _name="Foo" version="2.0" _section="Source">
  <metadata>
    <property name="mimetypes">text/x-c;text/x-csrc;image/x-xpixmap</property>
    <property name="globs">*.foo</property>
  </metadata>

  <styles>
    <style id="operator" _name="Operator" map-to="def:keyword" />
    <style id="member" _name="Member" map-to="def:type" />
  </styles>

  <definitions>

    <context id="members" style-ref="member">
      <keyword>ref</keyword>
      <keyword>alt</keyword>
      <keyword>pos</keyword>
      <keyword>num</keyword>
    </context>

    <context id="operators" style-ref="operator">
      <keyword>#</keyword>
      <keyword>$</keyword>
      <keyword>@</keyword>
      <keyword>[</keyword>
      <keyword>]</keyword>
      <keyword>:</keyword>
      <keyword>=</keyword>
      <keyword>:?</keyword>
      <keyword>&amp;</keyword>
    </context>

    <!--Main context-->
    <context id="opal" class="no-spell-check">
      <include>
        <context ref="members" />
        <context ref="operators" />
      </include>
    </context>

  </definitions>
</language>
```

The syntax does highlight, but only on some odd conditions. Specifically, any keyword in the `operators` context must be both preceded by and followed by a non-keyword character, lest it will fail to highlight.

[image: Screencap]

Should I be using a regex for these or did I just botch the XML? Also, why do the `members` keywords highlight without issue?